# can't import project folder to svn repository locally

Tags: svn

I try use svn on my local pc. I created local svn repository. Then created folder for my project. Try add this folder to svn repository, but get errors

```
Command: Import E:\Project1 to file:///E:/SVN_new  
Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///E:/SVN_new'  
Error: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL  
Error: Unable to open repository 'file:///E:/SVN_new'  
Completed!:
```

how can I import ny project folder and what url of svn should set?

Comment: What command line did you run to do the import?

Comment: And where is the repo? (how did you create it with svnadmin?)

Comment: the repo is on disk E:/SVN_new, I create that folder, then right click on it - Create repository here. Maybe I should do it in another way?

Comment: So you're using a GUI like TortoiseSVN rather than the command line then?

Comment: Well, try and show output of `svn --help` (is  ra_local supported in your TSVN) and `dir E:\SVN_new` (is dir really repo?)